# How to call adminhtml controller?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-controller

I want to call my custom adminhtml controller on form action. see my config file admin please and how to call controller.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mage2sol_Trackinglink>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mage2sol_Trackinglink>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <trackinglink>
        <class>Mage2sol_Trackinglink_Helper</class>
      </trackinglink>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <trackinglink>
        <class>Mage2sol_Trackinglink_Block</class>
      </trackinglink>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <trackinglink>
        <class>Mage2sol_Trackinglink_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>trackinglink_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </trackinglink>
      <trackinglink_mysql4>
        <class>Mage2sol_Trackinglink_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>        
              <tracklink>
                <table>tracklink</table>
              </tracklink>
        </entities>
      </trackinglink_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <trackinglink_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Mage2sol_Trackinglink</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </trackinglink_setup>
      <trackinglink_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </trackinglink_write>
      <trackinglink_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </trackinglink_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <trackinglink>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Mage2sol_Trackinglink</module>
          <frontName>admin_trackinglink</frontName>
        </args>
      </trackinglink>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <trackinglink module="trackinglink">
        <title>Trackinglink</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <tracklink module="trackinglink">
            <title>Manage Tracklink</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <action>admin_trackinglink/adminhtml_tracklink</action>
          </tracklink>
        </children>
      </trackinglink>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <trackinglink translate="title" module="trackinglink">
              <title>Trackinglink</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <tracklink translate="title">
            <title>Manage Tracklink</title>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
          </tracklink>
              </children>
            </trackinglink>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <trackinglink>
          <file>trackinglink.xml</file>
        </trackinglink>
      </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
                <observers>
                    <trackinglink_custom_order_view_info>
                        <class>trackinglink/observer</class>
                        <method>getSalesOrderViewInfo</method>
                    </trackinglink_custom_order_view_info>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
        </events>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this action url to get admin controller form action -

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/adminhtml_tracklink/your_form_action'); ?>" name="trackinglink" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally admin url's are working with secret code.

`$url = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("admin_trackinglink/<your_action_name>")`

When we using above code. The secret key will automatically be added to the URL.

```
<form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="POST">
```

you give as first parameter a route with a controller, where the method is just waiting for a controller name.

DON'T USE anything else than adminhtml/ as start of the url, because magento 1.9.2.2 forbids everything else.